# Help to find the point where method is triggered

Tags: objective-c, three20

I use the [**TTMessageController**](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTMessageController.m) in my project. I display it modally. Its navigation bar has by default two buttons, one to dismiss the composer and the other to send the message.

The problem is that after the user clicked on "send" the view gets closed automatically.

Here is the method from TTMessageController.m file that closes the view

```
- (void)cancel:(BOOL)confirmIfNecessary {
  if (confirmIfNecessary && ![self messageShouldCancel]) {
    [self confirmCancellation];

  } else {
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(composeControllerWillCancel:)]){
      [_delegate composeControllerWillCancel:self];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewController];
  }
}
```

So [self dismissModalViewController]; closes the view. The only method that is called in my code is the send method. But I can not see why the view closes since there is no cancel call in the send method.

Please have a look at the source: https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTMessageController.m

Do you find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a symbolic breakpoint in Xcode, to halt whenever a -dismissModalViewController message is sent. If you look at the stack trace, that might help you determine when it's getting called (this may be a new feature of Xcode 4).